# "Price slider " extension not working on iphone

Tags: extensions, iphone

I installed "Price slider " extension. Its working fine. But its not working on Iphone. Any idea?
extension link - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magehouse-free-ajax-layered-navigation-toolbar-with-price-slider-2-2-0.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often enough stuff doesn't work on touchscreen devices, because they might use different events for click (mouse) and tap (touchscreen), which means that it's good idea to capture both of them (there are several ways to do that, simplest being `.on("tap click")`, however it has its own set of compatibility issues).